# Chrome - Inline css works but stylesheet doesn't

Tags: css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I've written the following CSS and it works on Firefox but not on Chrome.

```
body
{
    background: darkorange;
    padding-top: 54px;
}
```

---

The CSS above is the **only** custom css that I have applied to my project.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" type="text/css"/>
```

This is on **Chrome** and it's **wrong**.

---

[image: This on Chrome and it's wrong]

This is on **Firefox** and it's **correct**

---

[image: This is on **Firefox** and it's **correct**]

What's even more stranger is that when I write the CSS inline it does work on both browsers.

```
<body style="padding-top: 54px; background: darkorange;">
```

Two questions:

1) Why is the CSS not working on Chrome?

2) Why is the CSS working when written inline?

Comment: Try inspecting your body tag to see what styles actually get applied.  You can hit "F12" to bring up the debugger tools, or right-click and select "inspect element" (or similar words).

Comment: Try loading your custom css file prior to bootstrap. Also make sure you are doing hard refresh to clear the cached version when you modify the css file.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are doing a hard refresh in the browser after changing the css file. CTRL+R or CTRL+F5 should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think it has anything related to bootstrap since there is no bootstrap class added to the element.

Second, double check your path to the css file and the  element

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Third, use Chrome Debugger tool. Right click, and inspect the body tag to see if there is any style applied.

I tested what you provided, works for me both firefox and definitely chrome. You can see it below.

[Open JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/010htd5w/)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS there is a file hierarchy. When you link a stylesheet in your head it is being read top down with the last file taking precedence over the first that you have called.

Ex

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/globals.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
```

Within this code, index.css will take priority over globals.css as it was the last to be accessed.

This is generally only an issue when you are trying to apply multiple effects to an element through two different stylesheets however in your case this can also be true. You may find that Bootstrap styling is taking precedence over your own.

Both the Chrome and Firefox debuggers can serve as useful to you to see what styles are being added to elements. I'd implore you to check what your debugger is telling you and to go from there.